# MySQL Subquery IN results

Tags: mysql, subquery

I want to use ids from query on my_table to select all field_b rows from my_table_2.

```
  SELECT field_b
  FROM my_table_2
  WHERE my_id_2 IN (
         SELECT my_id FROM my_table WHERE field_a = 1234
  );
```

I get `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'my_id_2' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'` executing the above query.

Below are example of my tables for reference:

```
  mysql> select * from my_table;
    +-------+---------+
    | my_id | field_a |
    +-------+---------+
    |     1 |    1234 |
    +-------+---------+
    |     2 |    1234 |
    +-------+---------+
    2 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from my_table_2;
+-------+-----------+
| my_id_2 | field_b |
+---------+---------+
|     1   |  5678   |
+-------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: perhaps try to use full name, ie `WHERE my_table_2.my_id_2 IN(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way

```
SELECT field_b
FROM my_table_2 m2
WHERE EXISTS (
     SELECT my_id FROM my_table 
     WHERE field_a = 1234 and m2.my_id_2=my_table.my_id
);
```

Answer (score 1):

That query can be rewritten as a simple join operation:

```
SELECT field_b
FROM my_table_2
INNER JOIN my_table ON my_table_2.my_id_2 = my_table.my_id
WHERE field_a = 1234;
```

Comment: This isn't necessarily the same semantics. The join can introduce duplicates.